# SET extra_float_digits = 3 in postgresql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Whenever I start Postgresql DB engine, I have almost 7-8 queries running in the background `SET extra_float_digits = 3`

I am not sure why these are running all the times. I know that the extra_float_digits variable adjusts the number of digits displayed for floating-point values in Postgresql, however I am not sure why these queries run in the background when I start the DB engine.

I already have the extra_float_digits = 3 in the config file. Even if I comment it out, these queries still run in the background..

need help..Thanks

Comment: If a connection is idle, Postgres' session stats will still report the last executed statement. Are you sure these queries are actually running?

Comment: Checked again and I see these and other queries as idle.. whats the purpose of this query? and is there a query_timeout which we can have so that these get timed out?

Comment: That query is not issued by Postgres, it's the application that connects to Postgres that runs those statements.

Comment: The thing is that I have too many Postgres processes running in the background when i run an application.. is there a way to find out why do I have these many processes ?

Comment: It's normal for client applications to run a bunch of `SET` commands on startup, to configure various things to their liking. You don't need to "time out" these statements - like I said, they're not running any more.

Comment: The session stats should tell you the IP address, and (maybe) the application name of the client process. Beyond that, there's not much we can tell you from here...

Comment: By the way, what's the application?

Answer (score 14):

The queries aren't really running. As Nick says in the comments, the connections will be in idle state. `pg_stat_activity` shows the last statement that finished running when a query is idle.

As for the other part: I'd say you're using PgJDBC. `SET extra_float_digits` ensures that PgJDBC doesn't lose precision when it gets floating point values from the database. It's part of the initial connection conversation. It's normal and you can ignore it. [If you're on a recent PgJDBC, send the additional connection parameter `assumeMinServerVersion=9.0` and it'll go away](https://github.com/pgjdbc/pgjdbc/issues/168).

So what you have there is a bunch of new, idle connections.

Look into your application / application server's configuration. Your connection pool probably doesn't have reasonable limits set.

Comment: @WinSupp Anything to say here? You've gone silent. Was my answer helpful?

Comment: This property does not seem to be documented (http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/index.html) and I also couldn't find this in the source for the 9.3 driver. Does "recent PgJDBC" mean, this is only available in the upcoming 9.4 driver?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a new connection is established, postgres triggers this `extra_float_digits` setting. 
Issue was with my database health check module.

Comment: What was the issue and how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with Java and Postgresql.
I've resolved this issue by using PGPoolingDataSource and Close connection.

Here how I've built my classes:

//Class Factory Connection:

```
public class FacConn {

    public static PGPoolingDataSource getConnection2() {
    PGPoolingDataSource source = new PGPoolingDataSource();
    source.setServerName("local");
    source.setPortNumber(5432);
    source.setDatabaseName("mydbname");
    source.setUser("LoginUser");
    source.setPassword("password");
    source.setAssumeMinServerVersion("9.0");
    source.setConnectTimeout(50000);        

    return source;      
    }
}
```

//Class userDAO - class to interact with database

```
public class UsuarioDAO {

    private PGPoolingDataSource poolDS = FabConexao.getConnection2();
    private Connection con = null;

    public User searchById(Integer id){
        try{con = poolDS.getConnection();}
        catch (SQLException e){throw new RuntimeException(e);}

        String sql = "Select * from people where id_people=?";
        ResultSet rs = null;

        try (PreparedStatement smtm = con.prepareStatement(sql)){
            smtm.setInt(1, id);
            rs = smtm.executeQuery();
            People people = new People();
            if(rs.next()){
                people.setId_People(rs.getInt("id_people"));
                people.setFirtname(rs.getString("firstname"));
                people.setLastname(rs.getString("lastname"));
                people.setAge(rs.getInt("age"));
                people.setActiv(rs.getBoolean("activ"));
            } 
            smtm.close();   
            return people;
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println( e.getClass().getName()+": "+ e.getMessage() );          
        }  finally {
            if (rs != null) {
                try {rs.close();} catch (SQLException e) { /* ignored */}
            }
            poolDS.close();
        }
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my option you can end this connections with a pg-command. For example:

SELECT pg_terminate_backend(t.pid)
  FROM (SELECT pid
          FROM pg_stat_activity
         WHERE state = 'idle' AND query like '%float%' AND state_change<(now() - interval '1 hour')) AS t;